# Filter through an array of objects and return the ones that meet all of the given conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, conditional-statements, filtering

So, I have this array of objects called "characters" (currently only 3 objects, but it's supposed to be much more) and I want to filter through this array with a function (or an array method) and for example: return every character's name, who is `character.bodyType: "tall"` or has `character.element: "fire"` AND is also `character.weapon: "sword"` user, based on how many parameter values I pass to the function.

I wrote a function "isThere" that takes 4 params max but I want to be able to call it with any number of values less than four and get the names based on only those parameter values. Let's say I want to display only the names of characters who are both tall and male. The result should be `['Igneus']` but instead I get `[ 'Renna', 'Igneus', 'Igneus', 'Dagon' ]` and I couldn't figure out the logic for it to only filter the ones that met both requirements and skipped duplicates and those that met only one of them.
If I want to see the names of "sword" characters only, the result should be `["Renna" , "Igneus]`... and so on and so forth.

My code is clearly unfinished and wrong, I tried several different approaches with if statements, this is just where I stopped. If it is possible to do with an array method, that's short and clean, I'll take it. I tried Array.filter() method but I just didn't know how to implement a 4 parameter function in it, or if it'spossible at all.

```
const characters = [
  {
    bodyType: "tall",
    element: "air",
    gender: "female",
    name: "Renna",
    weapon: "sword",
  },
  {
    bodyType: "tall",
    element: "fire",
    gender: "male",
    name: "Igneus",
    weapon: "sword",
  },
  {
    bodyType: "medium",
    element: "water",
    gender: "male",
    name: "Dagon",
    weapon: "spear",
  },
];


  function isThere(body, element, gender, weapon) {
    const arr = [];
    for (const char of characters) {
        if (char.bodyType === body) {
          arr.push(char.name)
        }
        if(char.element === element){
          arr.push(char.name)
        }
        if(char.gender === gender){
          arr.push(char.name)
        }
        if(char.weapon === weapon){
          arr.push(char.name)
        }
    }
    return arr;
  }


isThere("tall", undefined, "male", undefined)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be achieved using the [rest syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) on the args and the array method [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
const characters=[{bodyType:"tall",element:"air",gender:"female",name:"Renna",weapon:"sword"},{bodyType:"tall",element:"fire",gender:"male",name:"Igneus",weapon:"sword"},{bodyType:"medium",element:"water",gender:"male",name:"Dagon",weapon:"spear"}];

const isThere = (...args) => 
    characters.filter(char => 
        ['bodyType', 'element', 'gender', 'weapon'].every((key, index) =>
            args[index] === undefined || args[index]  === char[key]
        )
    )
    .map(({ name }) => name);

console.log(isThere("tall", undefined, "male", undefined));
console.log(isThere(undefined, undefined, undefined, "sword"));
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for, in terms of short way of doing it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Currently your code acts as a giant "or" - it pushes the name if any of the conditions are satisfied. You're actually looking for an "and". In addition, if a criteria is not specified, the character should immediately pass the condition, which is why I have added `(typeof ... !== "undefined" ? ... : ...)`.

```js
const characters = [{
    bodyType: "tall",
    element: "air",
    gender: "female",
    name: "Renna",
    weapon: "sword",
  },
  {
    bodyType: "tall",
    element: "fire",
    gender: "male",
    name: "Igneus",
    weapon: "sword",
  },
  {
    bodyType: "medium",
    element: "water",
    gender: "male",
    name: "Dagon",
    weapon: "spear",
  },
];


function isThere(body, element, gender, weapon) {
  const arr = [];
  for (const char of characters) {
    if ((typeof body === "undefined" ? true : char.bodyType === body) &&
        (typeof element === "undefined" ? true : char.element === element) &&
        (typeof gender === "undefined" ? true : char.gender === gender) && 
        (typeof weapon === "undefined" ? true : char.weapon === weapon)) {
      arr.push(char.name)
    }
  }
  return arr;
}


console.log(isThere("tall", undefined, "male", undefined));
```

Comment: You don't need a `typeof` check here since the parameters are declared but may be `undefined`, a simple equality check is fine `body === undefined` etc.

Comment: So the trick was to put a bunch of if conditions in a single big if. I did try nested if statements but the && operator part was wrong on my end so I couldn't get the desired results. This is how I should've done it. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

New concept: currying

```js
const characters = [
  {
    bodyType: "tall",
    element: "air",
    gender: "female",
    name: "Renna",
    weapon: "sword",
  },
  {
    bodyType: "tall",
    element: "fire",
    gender: "male",
    name: "Igneus",
    weapon: "sword",
  },
  {
    bodyType: "medium",
    element: "water",
    gender: "male",
    name: "Dagon",
    weapon: "spear",
  },
];


const partialMatch = (object) => (character) => Object.entries(object).every(([key,value]) => character[key] === value)

const myMatchingCharacters = characters.filter(partialMatch({bodyType:'tall',gender:'male'}))

console.log(myMatchingCharacters.map(({name}) => name))
```

Comment: no reason to call `Object.entries` on every filter iteration, create a closure over the entries before returning.

Comment: @pilchard - noice

Answer (score 0):

In case the OP does not want to plainly write each `filter` method like e.g. ...

- ```
  (({ bodyType, element, gender, name, weapon }) =>
    (bodyType === 'tall' || element === 'fire') && weapon === 'sword'
  )
  ```
- ```
  (({ bodyType, element, gender, name, weapon }) =>
    bodyType === 'tall' && gender === 'male'
  )
  ```

... but wants to use config like objects instead, then the OP needs to come up with helper methods like

- `every` and `any` which each create a single filter function based on the passed config
- and `and` as well as `or` where each creates a single filter function which does process a list of filter functions according to the helper methods logical meaning/purpose.

```js
function every(config) {
  return (item => Object
    .entries(config)
    .every(([key, value]) =>
      item[key] === value
    )
  );
}
function any(config) {
  return (item => Object
    .entries(config)
    .some(([key, value]) =>
      item[key] === value
    )
  );
}
function and(...requirements) {
  return (item => requirements
    .every(requirement =>
      requirement(item)
    )
  );
}
function or(...requirements) {
  return (item => requirements
    .some(requirement =>
      requirement(item)
    )
  );
}

const characters = [{
  bodyType: "tall",
  element: "air",
  gender: "female",
  name: "Renna",
  weapon: "sword",
}, {
  bodyType: "tall",
  element: "fire",
  gender: "male",
  name: "Igneus",
  weapon: "sword",
}, {
  bodyType: "medium",
  element: "water",
  gender: "male",
  name: "Dagon",
  weapon: "spear",
}];

// OP ... > who is character.bodyType: "tall"
//        > or has character.element: "fire"
//        > AND is also character.weapon: "sword"
console.log(
  '({ bodyType: "tall" } OR { element: "fire" }) AND { weapon: "sword" } ... conventionally ...', 
  characters
    .filter(({ bodyType, element, gender, name, weapon }) =>
      (bodyType === 'tall' || element === 'fire') && weapon === 'sword'
    )
);
console.log(
  '({ bodyType: "tall" } OR { element: "fire" }) AND { weapon: "sword" } ... by helper functions ...',
  characters
    .filter(
      and(
        any({ bodyType: "tall", element: "fire" }),
        any({ weapon: "sword" })
      )
    )
);

// OP ... > Let's say I want to display only the names
//        > of characters who are both tall and male.

console.log(
  '{ bodyType: "tall" } AND { gender: "male" } ... conventionally ...', 
  characters
    .filter(({ bodyType, element, gender, name, weapon }) =>
      bodyType === 'tall' && gender === 'male'
    )
);

// either ...
console.log(
  '{ bodyType: "tall" } AND { gender: "male" } ... by helper functions ...',
  characters
    .filter(
      and(
        any({ bodyType: "tall" }),
        any({ gender: "male" })
      )
    )
);
// ... or.
console.log(
  '{ bodyType: "tall" } AND { gender: "male" } ... by helper functions ...',
  characters
    .filter(
      every({ bodyType: "tall", gender: "male" }),
    )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Adam's approach can even be shortened into a one-liner but the readability suffers:

```js
const characters = [
  {
    bodyType: "tall",
    element: "air",
    gender: "female",
    name: "Renna",
    weapon: "sword",
  },
  {
    bodyType: "tall",
    element: "fire",
    gender: "male",
    name: "Igneus",
    weapon: "sword",
  },
  {
    bodyType: "medium",
    element: "water",
    gender: "male",
    name: "Dagon",
    weapon: "spear",
  },
];

const matched = characters.filter((crits=> pers => crits.every(([k,v]) => pers[k] === v))([['bodyType','tall'],['weapon','sword']]))

console.log(matched.map(({name}) => name))
```